# What's the correct way to remove all objects referenced by parent in array of references, mongoosejs

Tags: arrays, mongoose

Having parent-children relationship:

```
var parentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  children: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child'}
});
var childSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String });
```

I want to remove Parent and all its children referenced in children array.

What's the correct way to do this? forEach over children array is not a good way as I understand..

**EDIT**

I do it as follows:

```
Parent.pre('remove', function(next) {
   Child.remove( {_id: {$in: {this.children}}}, function(err) { 
      if ( err ) ...
   });
   next();
});
Parent.findById( req.params.parentId, function(err, parent) {
  parent.remove(function(err) {
    if (err) ....
  }
});
```

Comment: Why are you referring the Parent model in your children subschema?

Comment: Corrected. Thanks. The question remains.

Comment: @rlib What's wrong with how you're doing it now? That should work.

Comment: I don't know if it's "the right way". It works, yes.